# How to use FreeText in EF core 2.1

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, freetext

I see that Entity Framework core 2.1 has a new feature to use `FREETEXT`, but I am not sure how to use it as there are no examples that I can find online.

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/11484

Has anyone used it yet and could give me a quick example?

Comment: You already have an issue in [Full Text Search in EF Core 2.1](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/12461) which you should've mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

First make sure you have the relevant packages installed `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`.

Then ensure you have the following import:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
```

Now you can use the `FREETEXT` SQL function like this:

```
var results = context.Foos
    .Where(f => EF.Functions.FreeText(f.ColumnName, "search text"));
```

Note: You can see how this works in the unit tests, [for example](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/main/test/EFCore.SqlServer.FunctionalTests/Query/NorthwindDbFunctionsQuerySqlServerTest.cs#L108).

To create the full text index, there is currently no support for doing this automatically in Entity Framework Core. Instead, you need to manually add the code to the migration. So, create a migration as you normally do, open it up and add lines similar to this:

```
Sql("CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG ft AS DEFAULT", true);
Sql("CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON dbo.TableName(ColumnName) KEY INDEX UI_TableName_ColumnName WITH STOPLIST = SYSTEM", true);
```

Note the 2nd parameter in the call to `Sql` to suppress transactions. If you omit that you may get an error stating:

> CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG statement cannot be used inside a user transaction

Comment: Do, I need to index the column name I want to use?

Comment: Yes, you will need to set up the full text index first.

Comment: I'm getting `CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG statement cannot be used inside a user transaction.` when applying the custom migration. Any Ideas?

Comment: @Liero You need to suppress transactions in the `Sql` call, just call the overload with a value of `true` for the 2nd parameter e.g. `Sql("CREATE....", true);`

Comment: So, we're completely out of luck if we want to search more than one column?

Comment: @JonathanWood What makes you say that?

Comment: Because `EF.Functions.FreeText()` only accepts one column reference. My current websites that implement full-text search all index more than one column.

Comment: @JonathanWood But you can use that function multiple times.

Comment: I want one query that scans multiple columns. I don't think there's any way to chain multiple calls together but you'd have to include the same query with each one. I don't think that's possible.

Comment: @JonathanWood It's the same as any query, just do `FreeText(...) || FreeText(..)` or whatever.

Comment: @DavidG: Full-text search queries look like this: `CONTAINSTABLE([Table], *, @SearchTerm)`. The asterisk specifies that all full-text-indexed columns should be searched. So this is more optimized than an `OR` expression would seem to allow. It's possible there is an option I'm not aware of, but I've requested Microsoft [add support for more columns](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/22418).

Comment: Any idea if FromText is also available for MySQL?

Comment: @DavidG yes, I just found an extension method for SQL Server.