# Custom Entity Framework Core Migration Script?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I need to make a "full-text indexed" but I am using ef core 2.1 code first migration, but Full Indexes do not have first class support in core.

How can I write my own migration that would be applied while the other generated migrations are being applied?

Comment: `migrationBuilder.Sql` method is your friend. For more info, see [Migrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/) and [API Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/?view=efcore-2.1).

Comment: So, I generate the migration file then go in and manually change it or do I make a another file?

Comment: Manually change it. Your use-case with Full-Text Search is even mentioned in the [Empty Migrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/#empty-migrations) part of the first documentation link.

Comment: This was answered in your Github issue [Full Text Search in EF Core 2.1](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/12461) and an example was provided your in SO question [How to use FreeText in EF core 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51047514/how-to-use-freetext-in-ef-core-2-1).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to create empty migration and then in `Up` method you can write your SQL query.

1. Create Empty Migration by running Add-Migration command in Package
   Manager Console.
2. Add the SQL function in Up method like the following way.

`public partial class your_migration_name : Migration`
`{`

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.Sql(@"<YourQuery>");
}

protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.Sql(@"Drop <YourQuery>");
}
}
```

3. Run `Update-Database` in Package Manager Console.