# How do you do fulltext search with Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the following query:

```
SELECT Animals.name 
FROM Animals 
WHERE CONTAINS(*, 'feline AND black');
```

I am having trouble converting it to an Entity Framework Core query. I have a SQL Server with a catalog that has a few indexes.

I want to be able to use `FREETEXT` and `CONTAINS` to do a fulltext query on the tables. I cannot find the method in Entity Framework Core for fulltext search with `CONTAINS`.

Comment: As far as I know, EF Core does *not* support fulltext searching in SQL Server natively. You might need to package those queries up into stored procedure, which you can call from EF Core

Comment: Have you looked at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserverdbfunctionsextensions.freetext?view=efcore-2.1

Comment: I did look into that. Unfortunately, they don't have the method "CONTAINS" that can be used to use logical operators. So far it is looking like EF Core does not support fulltext searching.

Comment: I think the only way to get around this is just to perform raw sql queries with Entity Framework. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is possible as of EF Core 2.1.   You have to add a using statement for Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore but after that you can use it as shown below

```
var results = db.Widgets
    .Where(x => EF.Functions.FreeText(x.ColumnName, "search text"));
```

Comment: how to do it on all columns?

Comment: This answer also explains how to create the fulltext index that is required for this to work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51047763/1943145

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is posible using EF 6, just use EF.Functions.Contains

```
var results = db.Widgets
    .Where(x => EF.Functions.Contains(x.ColumnName, "search text"));
```

Important "search text" do not allow blank spaces you have to separate each word using logic operators like AND OR, for example if you want to search records with "green" and "blue", you have to put "green AND blue", not "green blue"