# EF Core freetext with child entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, freetext, entity-framework-core-2.2

EF Core 2.1 has added support for `FREETEXT`, as also discussed in [How to use FreeText in EF core 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51047514/how-to-use-freetext-in-ef-core-2-1?noredirect=1&lq=1). I have a different problem, however, using EF Core 2.2: Does EF Core's `FREETEXT` support child entities?

```
public class Customer
{
    public Name Name { get; set; }

    public List<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}
```

Name is an owned entity (value object), which works perfectly for searching:

```
public class Name
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Address is a child entity:

```
public class Address
{
    public string Street { get; set; }

    public string Number { get; set; }
}
```

This search works fine:

```
query.Where(c => EF.Functions.Freetext(c.Name.FirstName, searchTerm) || EF.Functions.Freetext(c.Name.LastName, searchTerm)
```

This search does not, as the final term cannot be translated to SQL:

```
query.Where(c => EF.Functions.Freetext(c.Name.FirstName, searchTerm) || EF.Functions.Freetext(c.Name.LastName, searchTerm) || EF.Functions.Freetext(c.Addresses.First().Street, searchTerm)
```

Is there any way around this, or will I need to use a SQL function? I've tried using a `Select()` statement, but that could also not be fully translated to SQL.

Comment: Apologies, Address should have been a `List` of `Address` objects. So it's the first `Address` in the list. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it! Apparently, `EF.Functions.FreeText(c.Addresses.First().Street, searchTerm)` cannot be evaluated client-side. However, this can:

```
EF.Functions.FreeText(c.Addresses.Any(a => EF.Functions.FreeText(a.Street, searchTerm))
```

So make sure `EF.Functions.FreeText()` receives a simple `string` as its first property, and use any other LINQ for selecting the `First()`, 'Last()', `Any()` and `All()` of child entities.

Answer (score 0):

The Docs for the FREETEXT method from EF Core 2.1 indicate that client-evaluation is not allowed. There is no Docs for EF Core 2.2 yet, but I assume it's not changed.

> This DbFunction method has no in-memory implementation and will throw if the query switches to client-evaluation.
>
> This can happen if the query contains one or more expressions that could not be translated to the store.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserverdbfunctionsextensions.freetext?view=efcore-2.1

Otherwise, you might consider adding a property on Customer, on which you can query directly, if it's really important for you to use FREETEXT. For example

```
public class Customer
{
    public Name Name { get; set; }
    public List<Address> Address { get; set; }
    public string DefaultStreet { get; set; }
}
```

I assume the addresses are on a list, based on your query.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Agreed, no client-evaluation is possible with `FREETEXT`, I'd noticed. But is there any way to add a `WHERE` clause to a child entity and NOT fall back to client-evaluation? (And yes, `Addresses` are on a `List`, sorry!)